# Error creating bean with name 'applicationAvailability'. Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

Estoy empezando con spring boot y hay algunos errores que no supe resolverlos. Estos errores no me dejan avanzar. Os muestro mi código

**Interface BeanMapper**

```
public interface BeanMapper extends com.devonfw.module.beanmapping.common.api.BeanMapper {

  <T> Page<T> mapPage(Page source, Class<T> targetClass);

}
```

**Interface BeanMapperImpl**

```
public class BeanMapperImpl extends BeanMapperImplOrika implements BeanMapper {


  public <T> Page<T> mapPage(Page source, Class<T> targetClass) {

    if (source == null) {
      return null;
    }

    List list = mapList(source.getContent(), targetClass);

    return new PageImpl<>(list, source.getPageable(), source.getTotalElements());
  }

}
```

**Clase BeansOrikaConfig**

```
@Configuration
public class BeansOrikaConfig extends BaseOrikaConfig {

  @Override
  @Bean
  public BeanMapper getBeanMapper() {

    return new BeanMapperImpl();
  }

  @Bean
  public Module configureObjectMapper() {

    ObjectMapperFactory objectMapper = new ObjectMapperFactory();
    return objectMapper.getExtensionModule();

  }

}
```

**Main**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class TutorialApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TutorialApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

**.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.capgemini.coedevon</groupId>
    <artifactId>template</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>template</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <devon4j.version>2020.04.001</devon4j.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.devonfw.java.boms</groupId>
                <artifactId>devon4j-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${devon4j.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.devonfw.java.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>devon4j-beanmapping-orika</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.devonfw.java.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>devon4j-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.devonfw.java.starters</groupId>
            <artifactId>devon4j-starter-spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**Errores**

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'applicationAvailability' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/availability/ApplicationAvailabilityAutoConfiguration.class]: BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importRegistry' available

    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importRegistry' available
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator.findCandidateAdvisors(AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator.java:92) ~[spring-aop-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:506) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        ... 18 common frames omitted
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importRegistry' available
```

Eso es todo :)

Comment: Revisa que todas las clases que tengas como dependencias de un Bean de Spring (y esperes que sean inyectadas) estén anotadas con: `@Componet`, `@Repository`, `@Service`, etc.